# Installing VMware. Error : Kernel headers for version 4.3.0-kali1-amd64 were not found

Tags: debian, software-installation, kali-linux, vmware, header-file

Trying to install VMware Player on Kali Rolling (debian Wheezy). When running VMware Player for first time after installation I get:

> Error: C header files matching your running kernel were not found. Refer to your distribution's documentation for installation instructions.

When pressing OK I have to enter a manual path for headers. Tried a find command in case something missing.

[image: First error img]

[image: Enter manual path img]

**UPDATE:**

```
/etc/apt/sources.list*

  deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
  deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2016.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 201$
  deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2016.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 201$
  deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian wheezy contrib
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry all, I finally fixed it after some time but forgot to post the answer! When I installed Kali, I din't make the updates so there were a lot of crucial updates pending. I finally solved it by going to Packages Update (from the Menu) and installing the pending update (for me it was >3GBs).

Note : Kali is a **rolling distribution** so after installation you must check to fetch the latest updates.

**UPDATE**: I didn't expect this question to become so frequently searched. So what will solve your problems, is type

`apt clean && apt update && apt dist-upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have a solution for you. Recently I have installed Kali Linux on my machine and I noticed a similar issue. Executing the following `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` will only fetch form the repositories in your sources.list file. Now in my case the repositories that I are available are outdated therefore I resulted to installing the Linux Headers manually by downloading the packages then using dpkg. Here is how accomplished that:

If your system is **32 bit**:

1) Wget the following files

```
 wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3.4-wily/linux-headers-4.3.4-040304_4.3.4-040304.201601230132_all.deb
 wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3.4-wily/linux-headers-4.3.4-040304-generic_4.3.4-040304.201601230132_i386.deb
 wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3.4-wily/linux-image-4.3.4-040304-generic_4.3.4-040304.201601230132_i386.deb
```

2) Install the following packages by issuing:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.3.4*.deb linux-image-4.3.4*.deb
```

3) Reboot your system:

```
sudo reboot
```

If your system is **64 bit**:

1) Wget the following files

```
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3.4-wily/linux-headers-4.3.4-040304_4.3.4-040304.201601230132_all.deb
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3.4-wily/linux-headers-4.3.4-040304-generic_4.3.4-040304.201601230132_amd64.deb
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3.4-wily/linux-image-4.3.4-040304-generic_4.3.4-040304.201601230132_amd64.deb
```

2) Install the following packages by issuing:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.3.4*.deb linux-image-4.3.4*.deb
```

3) Reboot your system:

```
sudo reboot
```

If you wish to uninstall the header files issue the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove 'linux-headers-4.3.4*' 'linux-image-4.3.4*'
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help bro! Unfortunately it didn't help. Actually when I try to install the packages with dpkg, after a bounch of lines this appears : Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-4.3.4-040304-generic

Comment: @JAAAY Try executing the following to try and resolve that error: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh `

Answer (score 0):

You need to install kernel headers:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)      ---              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-amd64'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-amd64'

Comment: Uhm.. please use this command: "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" (without quotes), then reboot and try again the command in my answer.

Comment: Again the same error while running apt-get install linux headers...Actually which of these headers is the one that i need ?? linux-headers-4.4.0-kali1-all        linux-headers-4.4.0-kali1-common
linux-headers-4.4.0-kali1-all-amd64  linux-headers-amd64
linux-headers-4.4.0-kali1-amd64

Comment: can you update your question posting your /etc/apt/sources.list ?

Comment: Updated the question!

Comment: That's strange.. are you sure that the command "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" worked for you? have you rebooted your VM?

Comment: Yes I know it is strange, maybe I will try to reinstall. Ty btw.